# Graphic overview SVN, summary about lines of code changed

Tags: svn, csv, project-management

Is there an easy way to show a project manager a few grpahics/numbers how much has changed in a SVN? FOr example to tell him, withn the last 2 weeks we have added 50 new files, 63000 lines of code changed, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it'll get you exactly the graphs you want *(and I cannot test, as I don't have it or this computer)*, but [**Tortoise SVN**](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) can give you some graphs, such as number of commits by date.

See for example [this page](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/bigpicture.html) for a couple of screenshots.

Another tools that might interest you is [**StatSVN**](http://www.statsvn.org/) -- and it seems that this one can get you a graph counting number of lines of code.

Another solution, instead of using some one-shot tool, would be to use some continuous-integration platform on your project *(like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), for example)*, and configure it to show this kind of reports.

This way, at any given time, anyone in your team could access those statistics, and follow the development of the project.

Comment: Hey there, I'm using tortoise, but somehow not enough... :(

Answer (score 1):

[FishEye](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/fisheye-documentation-home-298976794.html) from Atlassian

> FishEye is the on-premise source code repository browser for enterprise teams. It provides your developers with advanced browsing and search for SVN, Git, Mercurial, Perforce and CVS code repositories, from any web browser.